# I thought MySQL was free

Tags: mysql

I've always thought MySQL was a free database, but when I look at their site, all editions costs (plenty of) money.

Isn't there a free MySQL database for enterprise use?

Thanks

Comment: Community version is the free version, it is not supported.  Enterprises should pay money for a supported version if they want support. :)  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Comment: MySQL is open source, can be freely downloaded from several sites, can be downloaded as mariadb the non oracle version, you can compile from source or do what you like.  If you want enterprise support you pay.

Comment: Contact MySQL for their products. These questions should not be encouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Community Server is free to download and use but isn't supported. Enterprise version have support as you pay for this and other additional options.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Also a bit more info here about using the free version in production, https://serverfault.com/questions/239978/is-the-community-mysql-safe-for-production-use